# ¿Cómo detener una consulta si los valores que se ingresan no existen en SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Como puedo verificar que los datos que el usuario envía como parámetros de consulta, sino existen dichos datos que detenga la consulta. o sea si envía por ejemplo: `Samsung galaxy s6` y este no existe en la base de datos que cancele el query?

```
con.Open();                   
SqlCommand comando = con.CreateCommand();
comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "' AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'";
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
da.Fill(dt);   
DatagridView1.DataSource = dt; 
con.Close();
```

Comment: y como vas a saber si existen o no, antes de realizar la consulta? la unica forma de saberlo, es realizando la consulta. tal vez no estaria entendiendo tu problema

Comment: no tengo problema, sino que no se como seria la consulta para comprobar si existen o no, ese consulta que puse arriba es la que utilizo para que haga lo que el usuario pide pero quiero saber como hacer una consulta para que si estos datos no existen en sql que no ejecute esa consulta @gbianchi

Comment: y si haces la consulta y devuelve cero resultados, entonces no existen.. no se me ocurre de que otra forma podrias comprobarlo. La unica forma de ver si algo existe en la BD es haciendo una consulta a la BD. Si consultas cada campo por separado no sirve...

Comment: esta bien ya me diste una idea @gbianchi gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo consultando un [`COUNT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql) de los resultados que existan en tu origen de datos:

```
int Resultados = 0;

con.Open();
SqlCommand comando = con.CreateCommand();
comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
// SELECT COUNT traerá un número; si no existe nada devolverá 0.
comando.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "' AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'";
/*
 * ExecuteScalar traerá solo un dato del primer renglón
 * mientras que int.TryParse intentará convertir una cadena en número.
 */
int.TryParse(comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out Resultados);
con.Close();

if(Resultados > 0)
{
    con.Open();                   
    SqlCommand comando = con.CreateCommand();
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "' AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'";
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
    da.Fill(dt);   
    DatagridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    con.Close();
}
```

Para  traer el resultado del `COUNT` más directamente utilicé un [ExecuteScalar (ver aquí)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx#Ejemplos) y lo convertí a un número (con control de error `TryParse`). Una vez obtenido el número, se evalúa si es mayor a 0 y si lo es, entonces ejecuta la búsqueda normal.

---

Como recomendación, aprovecha la interfaz [`IDisposable`](http://speakingin.net/2011/11/29/uso-de-idisposable/) que implementa `SqlClient` para escribir un código más legible:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ToString())
{
    // Esta parte no es realmente necesaria, pero traduzco lo que puse arriba
    int Resultados = 0;
    using (SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "' AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        int.TryParse(comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out Resultados);
    }

    if(Resultados > 0) 
    { // Lo que importa realmente es a partir de aquí
        DataTable dt;
        using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "' AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                if (reader.HasRows) // Aquí se hace el control.
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd);
                    reader.Dispose();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                DatagridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    } // if innecesario.
}
```

---

## Mejor opción

Adicionalmente, lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar [consultas parametrizadas](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) que eviten la [inyección SQL](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/inyecsql/) en tu programa:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ToString())
{
    DataTable dt;
    using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @fec1 AND @fec2 AND [Descripcion de Articulo] = @desc AND Marca = @marca AND [Tipo de Articulo] = @tipo", con))
    {
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@fec1", SqlDbType.Date);
        cmnd.Parameters["@fec1"].Value = dtpdesde.Text;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@fec2", SqlDbType.Date);
        cmnd.Parameters["@fec2"].Value = dtphasta.Text;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmnd.Parameters["@desc"].Value = txtbusqueda.Text;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@marca", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmnd.Parameters["@marca"].Value = txtmodelo.Text;
        cmnd.Parameters.Add("@tipo", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmnd.Parameters["@tipo"].Value = cbtipo.SelectedItem;

        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmnd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            if (reader.HasRows) // Aquí se hace el control.
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd);
                reader.Dispose();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            DatagridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias hermano me ayudo

Comment: Me alegra que así fuera, Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Con el código que has proporcionado puedes *obtener la cantidad de resultados*.

Por ello, te sugiero cambiar el código así:

```
// En este método haces la consulta.
// El resultado de la consulta estará en un DataTable.
public DataTable ObtenerDatos()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    con.Open();                   
    SqlCommand comando = con.CreateCommand();
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    comando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "' AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'";
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
    da.Fill(dt);    
    con.Close();  

    return dt;
}

/// Ya en tu código, llamas al método "ObtenerDatos();".
DataTable tbl = ObtenerDatos();

// Aquí haces la validación que desees; incluso, si la variable
// tbl no tiene datos y la asignas al DataGridView, el control 
// DataGridView no mostrará nada.
if (tbl.Rows.Count == 0) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("No hay registros.");
}
else 
{
    DatagridView1.DataSource = tbl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando un count de sql:

```
int total = 0;

con.Open();
SqlCommand comando = con.CreateCommand();
comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
// SELECT COUNT traerá un número; si no existe nada devolverá 0.
comando.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN '" + dtpdesde.Text + "' AND '" + dtphasta.Text + "' AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= '" + txtbusqueda.Text + "' AND Marca='" + txtmodelo.Text + "' AND [Tipo de Articulo]='" + cbtipo.SelectedItem + "'";

int.TryParse(comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out total );
con.Close();

if(total > 0)
{
    // ejecutas lo que necesitas
}
```

Nota: Te recomiendo una libreria llamada [`Dapper`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) que te reduciria mucho el codigo que tienes, facil de utilizar y te protege de las [injecciones sql](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) a las que estas **muy vulnerable en ese codigo**.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
    using(con)
    {
        var total = con.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha BETWEEN @desde AND @hasta AND [Descripcion de Articulo]= @descripcion AND Marca= @marca AND [Tipo de Articulo]=@tipoArticulo", new{ desde = dtpdesde.Text, hasta = dtphasta.Text, descripcionArticulo = txtbusqueda.Text, tipoArticulo = txtmodelo.Text});

       if(total > 0)
       {
        //...
       }
    }
```